# logging.handlers.SysLogHandler omits leading whitespace in log message

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, logging, syslog

I am writing an application that logs both to `STDOUT` and to `syslog` using the `logging` module and a `logging.StreamHandler()` and `logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address='/dev/log')` handler respectively.

The formatter is set as

```
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(message)s'))
```

in both cases.

It now appears that leading whitespace (which I use to indent certain log messages for improved readability) is shown in `STDOUT` but not in `syslog`. Is there a way for the `SysLogHandler` to preserve the whitespace like the `StreamHandler` seems to be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

syslog daemons modify the data that's sent to them before display. For example, the data actually sent to the syslog daemon has a header as mandated by [RFC 5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424#section-6.2) which you don't see in the log you see in a log viewer. So the formatting of the message at `SysLogHandler` level won't guarantee a completely faithful representation (at least when it comes to leading spaces).